# Driving a Seiko Slave Clock

Tags: raspberry-pi, clock

I recently acquired a Seiko slave clock, like the ones used on ships. It has 2 coils, one for advance and one for retard. I'm intending on making a master clock for this out of an RPi or ESP32 or something similar, but I need to figure out how it works first.

The coils are marked 24 VDC/2000 Ohms, and I've found some semishady references that it wants an impulse every ½ sec, so my current idea is a 2 Hz square wave with a 24VDC peak, but do anybody on here know anything more about how these operate?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like a stepper motor.

Comment: I am familiar with the master-slave clock systems made by Gent of Leicester, which were a common installation throughout the British Empire. These used a synchronising pulse every 30 seconds. Because the slave clock illustrated has no seconds hand, I suspect it too uses the same timing system. However, the Gent system did not allow for retarding the clock. A description of a Gent master clock is at https://waitingtrain.blogspot.com/2008/08/pulsynetic-master-clock.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this movement out, it requires a pulse every 30 seconds at 24 VDC, alternating polarity every pulse. Turns out it uses the same idea as Gent of Leicester, cheers for that nudge in the right direction henros! The Seikos however have an additional coil that can be used to drive the clock backwards, thereby making it easy to reverse the clock when changing time zones!

The Seiko slave clocks also seem to be divided into 2 categories, the ones without the second hand are 30 second pulse clocks, while the ones with a second hand are of the 0.5 second pulse variety.